# Why is it that in a discrete metric space only eventually constant sequences are convergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I just read this result and was wondering what is the intuitive idea behind this ?

Comment: $\{x\}$ is a nbhd of $x$ in any discrete space!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sequence $(x_n)$ in a metric space $(X, d)$ converges to $x \in X$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_n, x) < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. Now consider the case where $d$ is the discrete metric and $\varepsilon \in (0, 1]$.

As for intuition, a sequence $(x_n)$ has limit $x$ if the terms of the sequence get closer and closer to $x$ as $n$ increases. If $(x_n)$ is not an eventually constant sequence, then the terms of the sequence are not getting closer to any fixed element $x$; the terms $x_n$ keep moving away from $x$ to create a distance of one between them.

Comment: I re read your answer and there is something that i just don't understand, why have you particularly considered the discrete metric space to be equipped with the discrete metric ? Isn't it true that a metric space can be discrete even when it is not equipped with the discrete metric in particular ?

Comment: What do you you mean by a discrete metric space if not a metric space where the metric is the discrete metric?

Comment: Well a metric space in which all the subsets are open.

Comment: Then $\{x\} = B(x, r)$ for some $r > 0$. Now, if $(x_n)$ is a sequence converging to $x$, choose $\varepsilon \in (0, r]$.

Answer (score 11):

In a discrete metric space, suppose a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$, then for $\epsilon = 1/2$, there must be $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
d(x_n, x) < 1/2 \quad\forall n\geq n_0
$$
But if $x_n\neq x$, then $d(x_n,x) =1$, and hence
$$
x_n = x \quad\forall n\geq n_0
$$

Comment: Are you considering the metric in this question to be the discrete metric ?

Comment: @johny : Yes, that is what a discrete metric space is!

Comment: Well,but the set of Natural numbers equipped with the usual metric in R also form a discrete metric space. So how can it be necessary that the discrete metric space should always be equipped with the discrete metric ?

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to a point $x$ not in this sequence, then the set of terms of the sequence $\{x_n\colon n\in\mathbb N\}$ is not closed. But in a discrete space every set is closed.