# Show if $(X,d)$ is a discrete space, then it is complete.

Tags: general-topology

Proof: 
Let $\{x\}$ be any Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Then for $\epsilon =1$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $m,n\geq N$, then $d(x_N,x_n)<1$... 
This is where I am stuck.

To complete this proof I want to show that $d(x_N,x_n)=1$ for all $n\geq N$ and then $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x_N$.

Comment: Hint: Figure out what's a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022355/prove-that-discrete-metric-space-is-complete

Comment: What you have written is somewhat inconsistent. First, I believe it should say $X$ instead of $\Bbb{R}$, as there is no mention of the real numbers in the title. Second, you want that $d(x_m,x_n)<1$ for all $m,n\geq N$. Finally, to prove that the sequence converges to $x_N$, what you need to do is show that $d(x_n,x_N)=0$ for all $n \geq N$. Now your idea is right though. Remember that convergent sequences on a discrete space are eventually constant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511836/why-is-it-that-in-a-discrete-metric-space-only-eventually-constant-sequences-are

Comment: How do you define a discrete space? Is $d$ the discrete metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an $N$ such that for all $n,m \ge N$ we have $d(x_n,x_m) <1$ which by definition of the discrete metric (!) means $x_n = x_m$.

So taking $m=N$ and any $n$, we see that for all $n \ge N$ we have $x_n = x_N$ so $(x_n)$ converges to the limit $x_N$.

So every Cauchy sequence converges and $(X,d)$ is complete.

Answer (score 2):

In a discrete space, sequences which differ from constant sequences only at finite points are the only convergent sequences. And a Cauchy sequence is such a sequence in a discrete space.